# Protocol buffer deserialization and a dynamically loaded DLL

Tags: c#, reflection, protobuf-net

I am using protobuf-net for my protocol buffering. I have a dll I am loading dynamically. I can create an instance of a data class contained within the dll, and I can use and modify the created data object. However, When I attempt to serialize/deserialize the data object I get the following crash:

{"Unable to identify known-type for ProtoIncludeAttribute: MyDataDLL.MyDataClass, MyDataDLL, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"}

and sometimes a crash saying that MyDataClass is not a subclass of MyBaseClass, or something like that. MyDataClass definitely inherits from MyBaseClass, and MyBaseClass has a ProtoInclude tag for MyDataClass .

```
Assembly theAssembly = Assembly.LoadFrom("MyDataDLL.dll");

Type theType = theAssembly.GetType("MyDataDLL.MyDataClass");

object theData = Activator.CreateInstance(theType);

using (FileStream theStream = File.Open(fileName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
{
    MethodInfo method = typeof(ProtoBuf.Serializer).GetMethod("Deserialize").MakeGenericMethod(theType);
    theData = method.Invoke(null, new object[] { theStream });                      
}
```

The crash happens on "method.invoke"

If I reference the dll in the project and use it that way,  I don't get the crash. So I know it is a working dll.

---

Update: Yes, MyDataClass and MyBaseClass are in the same assembly.

Here's a list of what my code does differently then your test class, though it's probably not extensive:
MyDataClass is the 4th in a list of 7 ProtoIncludes.

MyBaseClass contains all the data fields, MyDataClass contains the logic for functions that manipulate these data fields. So there are no ProtoMember calls in MyDataClass.

MyBaseClass implements the IExtensible interface and has the following function to handle additional data:

```
private ProtoBuf.IExtension extensionObject;
ProtoBuf.IExtension ProtoBuf.IExtensible.GetExtensionObject(bool createIfMissing)            {
    return ProtoBuf.Extensible.GetExtensionObject(ref extensionObject, createIfMissing);
}
```

Its probably not affecting anything, but my ProtoContracts use the Name parameter.

Comment: Re "Any additional thoughts?"; I didn't see your edit until you added a comment; I can change the test to reflect the update (when I get a second), but I'm not sure that IExtensible etc would impact this.

Comment: I know it has been a while - but I've now managed to reproduce this. Let me know if you are still interested in a fix...

Comment: Yeah, definitely want to know a fix. The original task was sort of put to the side, but out of general interest I'd like to know what the problem was. Plus, I may very well have to finish it.

Comment: Damn - I didn't spot your reply (it would have been better as a comment on my post!). This is due to the "load context" - i.e. how you load the dll. I've put one level of "fix" into the binary (available a while ago) - or for "full" support the way to do it is to hook the AppDomain.AssemblyResolve event. Let me know if you want more detail. (but reply on my post so I see it!)

Answer (score 1):

OK, I will investigate. I've logged this [here](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/issues/detail?id=45). Should be fun ;-p
Out of interest, are `MyDataClass` and `MyBaseClass` in the same assembly?

By the way; in the next drop, I intend including `Serialize` etc that accept a `Type` (rather than generics) - this will make the "in progress" RPC stack much simpler, and will help your usage too.

---

Update; I've added a [unit-test](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/source/browse/trunk/Examples/Issues/Issue45.cs) and (in a separate dll, loaded via `Assembly.LoadFrom` [test classes](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/source/browse/trunk/LateLoaded/FooBar.cs)). The unit-test passed. Please can you clarify what your code does differently (I need something I can reproduce in order to fix it).